# How to 'see' the active section of an induction hob

Tags: electromagnetism

We got a new induction hob (Neff) but it does not indicate the extent of each hob ring. Is there any way of "seeing" the extent of each hob?

I thought of using iron filings on a sheet of paper, but it needs a pot to activate the hob. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using aluminum foil instead of paper? A thick enough sheet of aluminum should be able to activate the hob.

Comment: Or a rimmed baking sheet and water.

Comment: @Puk I'll try that (when I get the iron filings)

Comment: @mmesser wouldn't that be just the same as a pot?

Comment: It would be a pot with a thin bottom that doesn't conduct heat especially well. It would heat up right over the induction coils and boil water right there.

Comment: @mmesser Yes, but I want to see the extent of the hob and the baking sheet would cover it up. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The coils are where you see water bubbling on the bottom as it starts to boil. In a thicker pan, the heat spreads out more and you might not be able to tell as easily.

Comment: @mmesser Now I get you! That's a great idea, I'll try it out. Basically the larger the tray better. Need to find a tray that reacts to the inductive current though.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used one of these before and don't know a lot about them, but if the glass cover on your hob is anything like that found on infrared electric hobs, you might be able to see right through it with an infrared camera. That said, this isn't guaranteed to work because for induction heating, the cover doesn't have to be transparent in the infrared.

[image]
[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/58781h/my_infrared_game_camera_can_see_through_my_stove/)

Comment: Well, as I don't have an infrared camera I can't try that out, but I doubt it's transparent - it's very well made...